# Can I install an .apk file of one project in other project?

Tags: android, apk

If suppose I have apk file, and I want to install that apk file when button is clicked in my current project. Is that possible?

Comment: You can not access code objects of other APKs

Comment: Am i right that you want to install application A on buttonclick inside of application B?
Like in the PlayStore app ?

Comment: ya exactly I want that only.

Comment: int APP_INSTALLED_REQUEST_CODE = 11111;
                Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("D:/CSipSimple-src/viabee.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                startActivityForResult(installIntent, APP_INSTALLED_REQUEST_CODE);                 error coming when i click on button in mobile

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have made an application A and want to launch that application from anoter app B.

In the manifest of your app A, find the activity you want to open when user launch add add :

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.your.package.SOME_ACTION" />
</intent-filter>
```

So you should have something like :

```
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:name=".choosecountry.ChooseCountry"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.your.package.SOME_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now go to your app B and when you want to launch the app A :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.your.package.SOME_ACTION");
startActivity(intent);
```

But doing that, any application present on the device can launch your app A using this action in an intent.

Answer (score 0):

Upon button click, execute the following snippet:

```
    int APP_INSTALLED_REQUEST_CODE = 11111;

    Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/file/app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivityForResult(installIntent, APP_INSTALLED_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will open the installation prompt you know from the PlayStore app.

If you need further information about how to place files in your project and how to get them, please have a look at part 2 of [this Blog post](http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/06/14/Android-Beginners-Intro-to-Resources-and-Assets.aspx).

Comment: what we have specify in this place "application/vnd.android.package-archive"

Comment: You have to keep it like that. it defines the type of the file, like "image/png" or "text/plain". All you have to add its the apks filepath.

Comment: error is coming parse error. There was a error while parsing the package.. it showing like that

Comment: Please provide the complete code you used and the errorlog you got

Comment: int APP_INSTALLED_REQUEST_CODE = 11111;
                Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("D:/CSipSimple-src/viabee.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                startActivityForResult(installIntent, APP_INSTALLED_REQUEST_CODE); // error coming on button click I installed it on mobile

Comment: Your path leads to your computers harddrive :D you have to add the apk to your projects assets folder and get it from there.

Comment: See the edited answer to get a link to a tutorial about how to use the assets folder

Comment: even I using this also getting same error.  installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("stream")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

Comment: error gone but it opening the basic apps of the phone like call settings. network settings etc.. whys this is happening